# Cell Fracture not appearing when activated

Tags: interface, add-on

I just installed the latest version of Blender v2.72 because I wanted to play around with its cell fracture addon.

I go into user preferences and check the box to activate cell fracture. Save Preferences and exit the menu.

I go into edit mode and select the cube in the scene and look for cell fracture on the left tool menu and it is not there. In all the tutorials/demos I have seen of this it has always just appeared in this menu.

Is there a step I have missed?

Comment: Works for me.. Does it work if you press *Load factory settings* in the file menu before enabling the addon?

Comment: You cell fracture in object mode, not edit mode!

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Care to add that as an answer (perhaps with a bit more detail)?

Comment: Look in the 2nd layer (hit 2, above keyboard, not on the number pad).

Answer (score 2):

As [GiantCowFilms said](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13770/cell-fracture-not-appearing-when-activated#comment18590_13770), the cell fracture addon is used in [*object mode*](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/introduction.html):

[image]